# Protect images uploaded with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, sendfile

I am building a site where I want to protect certain images from download. Only authorized users would be able to download them.

As I upload images with Carrierwave, they are stored inside `public/uploads/image`. Users can download them via link:

```
def transmit
    send_file(Rails.root.join('public' , 'uploads', 'image', filename.to_s)
end
```

How can I protect images inside `image` folder so unauthorized users can't access them? Let's say `users` table has boolean column `authorized`.

What would be the best way to do it?

**EDIT1:**

I know I can make `before_action` which wont allow unauthorized user to download it via download link but the image is still accessible if the user knows path to the folder where are images stored.

Comment: Don't store them in the public folder - store them elsewhere in the filesystem.

Comment: @sevenseacat, Thank you. The problem is that I need some versions of images available for public display so how can I accomplish that? Can I store different image versions to different locations? I would like to have some thumbnails store inside public folder and originals inside private folder.

Answer (score 2):

Normally carrierwave store images in public/uploader directory.

```
def store_dir
 'public/my/upload/directory'
end
```

.

If you store files outside the project root folder, you may want to define cache_dir in the same way:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def cache_dir
   '/tmp/projectname-cache'
  end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I now have thumbnails available to public? Is there a way to store different image versions in different locations?

Comment: store all thumbs in public directory as specified above and store your actual images in cache_dir and use retrieve_versions_from_store to retrieve file